# creating a multiple timer with single signal handler in linux?

Tags: c, linux, timer, handler, rtos

I created a program containing the single signal hander to handle multiple timer. This timer is used to call the specific task for every 2ms, 10ms and so on. But it is not working. Could anyone help me in this :(

http://www.graphics-muse.org/wp/?p=868
[how to solve this multiple linux timer with single signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22064264/how-to-solve-this-multiple-linux-timer-with-single-signal-handler)

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the following:

1. Setup your signal handler with `sigaction`, ensuring the handler's signature is `void handler(int, siginfo_t*, void*)`.
2. Create a number of timers with `timer_create`, each specifying a different `sigevent` structure (in particular the `sigev_value`).
3. In the signal handler, process the `siginfo_t` structure and use either of the following fields to determine which timer expired `si_int`, `si_ptr` (one of these will correspond to the `sigev_value` in step 2) or use `si_timerid`. Of course, if you use the `si_timerid` field, there's no need to define `sigev_value` in step 2.

That way, the signal handler can identify which timer triggered the signal and can appropriate action.